# Select a record where value is max in CouchDB

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a couchdb database with 156 json documents. I want to find the max of a certain value in the documents and then emit the whole document that contains that maximun value. I used this code but it doesnt seem to work. This may help you understand what i mean.

```js
function(doc) {
    var i,m;
    for (i = 0; i < doc.watchers.length; i++)
        m = Math.max(m,doc.watchers[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < doc.watchers.length; i++)
            if (m = doc.watchers[i])
                emit(doc.watchers[i], doc.watchers);
}
```

I would also like to select the 2 top documents, that have the max value.

Comment: Would this have worked if the "if" had used == instead of = ?

Answer (score 0):

Just using a map function won't work because the way map/reduce works doesn't make available the complete set of keys and values to the map function at the same time. 
I would use a reduce function for that. Something like this:

**Map function**

```
function(doc) {
  var i,m;
  for (i = 0; i < doc.watchers.length; i++) {
    emit([doc._id, doc.watchers[i]], doc.watchers);
  }
}
```

*Reduce function*

```
function(keys, values) {
  var top=0;
  var index=0;
  for (i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
    if (keys[i][1] > top) {
      top = keys[i][1];
      index = i;
    }
  }
  return({keys[index], values[index]})
}
```

For this strategy to work you need to query using group_level=1, so that couch passes the results grouped by document id to the map function.
I haven't tested this solution and it doesn't solve your second question yet. I can refine it if you think it goes the right way.